# meteor template not updating

Tags: javascript, templates, meteor, live

I create a meteor template on button click like this:

```
Template.main.events({
    'click input': function(event)
    {
        var templateInstance = Meteor.render(Template.chatfield({name:"james"}));
        document.body.appendChild(templateInstance);
    }
});
```

This creates a template filled with the chat messages from the user.

I also use a .created method on this template:

```
Template.chatfield.created = function()
{
    var theData = this.data;
    Template.chatfield.users = function()
    {
        return Guys.find({name:theData.name});
    }
}
```

The template html code looks like this:

```
<template name="chatfield">
    <div id="messages">
        {{#each users}}
        {{#each messages}}
            <p>{{this}}</p>
            <br>
        {{else}}
            <p>No messages inner yet.</p>
        {{/each}}

        {{else}}
            <p>No messages yet.</p>
        {{/each}}
    </div>
</template>
```

I will now add users to the collection, for instance by just writing this in the chrome console:

```
Guys.insert({name:"james",messages:["hello","world","wow","cool"]});
```

When I now press the button, the template gets display as I want it to be.

The problem is, that if I update the 'Guys' collection (again in chrome console):

```
Guys.update({name:"james"},{$push:{messages:'my new message'}})
```

Nothing happens. When I press the button again the new message is visible. But I want it to rerender as soon as the user adds a message. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like need to display multiple users, each with multiple messages, and the button is kind of an 'add a new user.'  When there are no records, none should display.  Each record should display (or the helper can narrow that down).

First, drop the idea that when you click a button, you do something to the dom.  In meteor, you do something to the data, and meteor takes care of showing it.

```
Template.main.events({
    'click input': function(event)
    {
        Guys.insert({name:"james",messages:["hello","world","wow","cool"]});
    }
});
```

chatfield is always ready to show records.  When none to show, it is invisible.

Where you would have inserted chatfield, put

```
{{>chatarea}}
```

helpers

```
Template.chatarea.messageList = function() {
    return this.messages;
}
Template.chatarea.guys = function() {
        return Guys.find()
}
```

template

```
<template name="chatarea">

  {{#each guys}}
    <div class="user">
        <p>{{name}}</p>

        <div id="messages">
      {{#if messageList}}
        {{#each messageList}}
            <div class="message">
                <p>  i know you are but what am i? </p>
            </div>
        {{/each}}  
      {{else}}
            <p>No messages yet. whazzzuppp?</p>
      {{/if}}
        </div>
    </div>
  {{/each}}

</template>
```

This is extracted from working code and edited, but not tested.  Please let me know if something fails.